# Material UI components lose their styling after deployment, How to fix this?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer

I am using material UI drawer with styled-components. I have added some custom styling to navbar and drawer like changing background color of navbar and drawer etc. Everything works fine on localhost but when I deploy it anywhere like surge, vercel etc, somehow styling of these components gets removed. I have used several hosting services like firebase, surge, vercel and netlify. This issue persists no matter which hosting service I use. This is how my drawer looks like in localhost:

[image]

After deploying, this is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-grass-l7v8mf?file=/demo.js

Here is deployment link: https://csb-l7v8mf-orpyzekrn-dev-sardarabdul.vercel.app/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material styling not loading in production build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216686/material-styling-not-loading-in-production-build)

Comment: Codesandbox I shared above is running on latest versions, unfortunately this doesn't solve this issue. @AhmedSbai